# How to retrieve data from an editbox in a GUI

Tags: function, matlab, user-interface, user-defined-functions

I have an edit box in my GUI. User inputs a number into the editbox and then pushes a pushbutton. when the pushbutton is pressed an external function is called. for the external function i need the number entered in the editbox. How can i used 'handles' to retrieve the data input in the edit box?

This is the code for my opening function

```
% --- Executes just before NEWSTALLGUI is made visible.
function NEWSTALLGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to NEWSTALLGUI (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for NEWSTALLGUI
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
set(handles.EnterSpeed,'string','0');

% UIWAIT makes NEWSTALLGUI wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);
```

This is the code for my editbox

```
function EnterSpeed_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to EnterSpeed (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of EnterSpeed as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of EnterSpeed as a double
user_speed=str2double(get(handles.EnterSpeed,'string'));
```

this is the code for my pushbutton

```
% --- Executes on button press in Calculate.
function Calculate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Calculate (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
Newfunction(user_speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [Problems with GUI, unable to use handles to store variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325567/problems-with-gui-unable-to-use-handles-to-store-variables/15329484#15329484)

Basically use:
editnum = get(editbox_handle,'string');

Then you'll probably want to convert it to a number.

Edit:

```
function NEWSTALLGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to NEWSTALLGUI (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for NEWSTALLGUI
handles.output = hObject;
handles.user_speed = 0;


% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
set(handles.EnterSpeed,'string','0');

% UIWAIT makes NEWSTALLGUI wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);
```

-

```
function EnterSpeed_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to EnterSpeed (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of EnterSpeed as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of EnterSpeed as a double
handles.user_speed=str2double(get(handles.EnterSpeed,'string'));
```

-

```
function Calculate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Calculate (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
Newfunction(handles.user_speed);
```

-

I think you could alternatively just use:

```
Newfunction(str2double(get(handles.EnterSpeed,'string')));
```

But whatever floats your boat. Also, you should check if the input is a number too before calling the Newfunction... Using str2double on something else other than a number will return a "[]."

Comment: I have used this  user_speed=str2double(get(handles.EnterSpeed,'string')<br/> but i am still getting error messages. I have defined it as 0 before my opening function

Comment: Use setappdata(figurehandle,'user_speed',user_speed) during the opening function. During the button callback, use getappdata(figurehandle,'user_speed'). Furthermore, use setappdata during the callback of the editbox to update user_speed. If you post some code it would be more helpful.

Comment: you need a way to pass information between callbacks. For the EnterSpeed_Callback use: handles.user_speed = str2double(...). Then for the Calculate_Callback use: Newfunction(handles.user_speed). Also make sure to initialize handles.user_speed = 0 in the opening function. Let me know if this works. You're using GUIDE so I'm doing this by what I remember. Check my edited answer.